# Surface go 2 to monitor with usb hub

Tags: usb, keyboard, display, hdmi, microsoft-surface

I have surface go 2 and just bought a monitor and wireless keyboard and mouse. As the surface go 2 only has one usb c port I bought an adaptor to HDMI. Monitor works fine with surface go 2 with HDMI cable, including audio.

USB dongle for mouse and keyboard plugged into monitor but not working. Can anyone advise if I can make this work and cheapest option if I need to buy something else please. Thanks

Comment: There are USB-C docks that have all the connectors you want. You'll just need to check they're compatible.

Comment: As above. You need a dock with HDMI and/or DP + USB(A) ports + Ethernet (optional) + Others (optional). If you have a simple USB-C to HDMI it only works for HDMI. Any USB ports in the monitor need an USB(A) uplink. Pleaser read your monitor's manual to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

On my monitor, the USB port is just for looping. You have already converted your USB port on the computer to HDMI. I am not aware of any method of converting HDMI to USB. That is, I don't see how the USB information from the monitor is going to go across a HDMI port.

You need to have a USB hub on you computer to "split" (as it were) the ports at that point.